# .Net Library style Comments

Tags: c#, .net, comments

.NET Framework proposes "///" for documentation in code. However, when I see the .NET library, I see they are using normal comment starting with "//". Also, I see that due to that the APIs look clean. See below screenshot:

[image: .NET Library comment style and resulting arrangement]

Notice that collapsed box shows only ellipses("...") and are placed in front of method declaration. But when I try to follow the same, I do not get the desired result. See below screenshot:

[image: When I Use the comments]

Notice that I get "//" characters along with ellipses("..."). Plus, I cannot get the field/method and comment to be placed on the same line.

How do I achieve the same result? Is there any trick that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I see the .NET library

You're not looking at the actual source code. That's just a representation of the metadata, generated for you by Visual Studio. It looks like some documentation is being pulled in from somewhere (that doesn't happen on my box in the way I've just tried it, but that's a different matter). You can tell this isn't real source code because there are constructors declared with no body.

If you look at genuine source code, e.g. [ReferenceSource for TcpClient](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,943f9db3a7511918) you'll see triple-slash comments. Interestingly, the [.NET Core code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs) doesn't have any XML comments either, but I *suspect* that's because they're defined elsewhere, as part of .NET Standard. (There's an [XML file](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/blob/master/xml/System.Net.Sockets/TcpClient.xml) in the `dotnet-api-docs` repo, but it's not immediately clear what that's generated *from*...)

When it comes to your own code, I'd strongly recommend just using the `///` syntax. `/** ... */` should work as well, but I don't remember ever seeing that in C# code. `//` is *not* a valid way of writing an XML comment in C#.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am aware that what I am looking at is not actual code, but I like the way it is represented in Visual Studio. I have tried using "///" for documentation too, but result is not that good either after collapsing. Mostly, I end up collapsing them again and again while scrolling through code. Looks more cluttered and difficult to concentrate on the code. (IMHO)

Comment: @Himanshu1983: It's really not clear what you're asking for I'm afraid, but I think you'll need to accept that you can't use `//` to generate XML documentation. If this is really just "I don't like the way Visual Studio collapses comments" then it's not really a question that we can answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My question was about if it is possible to get the similar behavior. I am already using documentation tags, but that was not I saw when I went to that class metadata. So, I assumed I was missing something there. Anyways, thanks for your time. Let's see if we get any interesting insights on this.